# Using sessions inside of a while loop to limit output

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have this script to limit the output of a MySQL database so that when a string is detected to be more than 140 characters long the script treats it as 2 lines instead of one.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $stringl = "$input";
    if ((strlen($stringl) > 140) && (!$_SESSION["" . $row['ID'] . ""]) && (!empty("".$_SESSION["text-lines"].""))) {
        $_SESSION["" . $row['ID'] . ""] = "" . $row['ID'] . "";
        $_SESSION["text-lines"] = $_SESSION["text-lines"] - 1;
    }
```

I am storing the unique ID of the string in a session to avoid this code being ran again when the page is refreshed but it doesn't work:

**Presently** if one string contains more than 140 characters, 1 is deducted from the text-lines session every time the script is refreshed.

**The expected result** is for 1 to be deducted once from text-lines session and then that same line wouldn't be able to deduct another line from text-lines.

Comment: What is the value of "$input" I don't see where this is coming from and also you have not properly closed your if statement, you need to add another "}"

Comment: Input is declared earlier in the script. But it's basically just a bunch of text. There's some other code beneath this thus the while loop isn't closed in example I posted.